# Adding number values to elements in a string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int, codeblocks

So I am 2 weeks into my first C++ class and I am hopelessly stuck on my current assignment. I have to create a list of world problems and have a user place them in their order of importance.

Right now I am trying to assign number values so the user can easily call them up by typing 1-5 to organize them. The code I have written doesn't work and I'm just trying to see if I missed something.

```
int main()
{
    string topics[5]{"World Hunger", "Government Oppression", "Genocide", "Disease", "Poor Education"};

    int responses[2][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}};

    topics[5] = responses[5];
    return 0;
}
```

Error: Invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'char'

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do?  Even if `topics[5] = responses[5]` were working, it'd just change `"Poor Education"` in your topics array to the value of `5`.  Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I need to make each topic correspond with a number so the user can input 1-5 to choose each topic. That's what I'm trying to do, give it a value of 5

Comment: You don't really need to save these values then, do you?

Comment: Oh nice. Wow, I'm a noob :p Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just be sure to check the "Accept Answer" so the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    std::cout << i+1 << ". " << topics[i] << std::endl;
}
std::cin >> userChoice;

if(userChoice == topics[0] || userChoice == "1") {
    //etc
} else if(userChoice == topics[1] || userChoice == "2") {
    //etc
} else if(/*etc etc etc*/) { //....
```